# Javapns issue - stuck on pushManager.sendNotification( client, aPayload ); function

Tags: apple-push-notifications

Everytime I try to send a notification

Get the following error:
Connection initialized...
Attempt failed... trying again
preclose
in finally
`enter code here`java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at ts.javapns.back.PushNotificationManager.sendNotification(PushNotificationManager.java:199)
    at org.apache.jsp.japnslist_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.japnslist_jsp:118)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:322)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:291)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:241)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

```
enter code here
```

What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?
Windows XP, newest version of javaapns

```
    // APNs Server Host & port      
    String HOST = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";      
    int PORT = 2195;      
    // Badge      
    int BADGE = 6;      
    // iPhone's UDID (64-char device token)      
    String iPhoneId = "aebf53cc8d6bfaf47dace40747091fa5b0fc837b...";      

    String certificate = "C:/webapplication/WEB-INF/cert.p12";      
    String passwd = "password";  

    System.out.println( "Setting up Push notification" ); 


    //Set system properties .....
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/var/www/apns/<apple.keystore>"); 

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "<pass>"); 


   try {              
   // Setup up a simple message              
 PayLoad aPayload = new PayLoad();              
 aPayload.addBadge( BADGE );              
 System.out.println( "Payload setup successfull." );              
 System.out.println ( aPayload );              

 // Get PushNotification Instance              
 PushNotificationManager pushManager = PushNotificationManager.getInstance();       

 System.out.println( "Linking iPhone's UDID (64-char device token) to stringName" );  

 // Link iPhone's UDID (64-char device token) to a stringName              
 pushManager.addDevice("iPhone", iPhoneId);              
 System.out.println( "iPhone UDID taken." );              
 System.out.println("Token:"+pushManager.getDevice("iPhone").getToken());              

 // Get iPhone client              
 Device client = pushManager.getDevice( "iPhone" );              
 System.out.println( "Client setup successfull." );     


 // Initialize connection              
 pushManager.initializeConnection( HOST, PORT, certificate, passwd,   SSLConnectionHelper.KEYSTORE_TYPE_PKCS12);              
 System.out.println( "Connection initialized..." );        


 // Send message              
 pushManager.sendNotification( client, aPayload );     
 System.out.println( "Message sent!" ); 

 //Remove device
 pushManager.removeDevice(iPhoneId); 
 System.out.println( "Removing Device" );

 System.out.println("# of attempts:" + pushManager.getRetryAttempts() );              
 pushManager.stopConnection();              
 System.out.println( "done" );          
} catch (Exception e) {              
   e.printStackTrace();          
}
```

As far as I can tell I am having an issue at this point in PushNotificationManager.java file

Function:
     public void sendNotification(Device device, PayLoad payload)

at this line of sendNotification:
        this.socket.getOutputStream().write(getMessage(device.getToken(), new PayLoad() ));

Socket is closed but I do not know why it would be?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

JavaPNS was recently updated to 2.0, and fixed ALL reported issues up to the release date.  It does fix the issue you are describing.

Sylvain

Answer (score 0):

Don't we have to specify the sanbox server for development or production server for the AdHoc?